# Does ozone (O₃) gas have a color?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Does ozone have a color or is it colorless? I have heard that ozone has a bluish color.

Could someone explain this observation scientifically?

Comment: This is pretty Googleable, and I'm closing it as such. If anyone disagrees, please let me know (with a reason)

Comment: Well, of course this is googlable, but why closing for "too localized"?

Comment: I googled this. I got two answers. I just say it in question. Bluish and colorless. Also a specific explanation not getting. Also I think a question closing because of its Googleable not a good practise and discouraging.Thanks.. :(

Comment: @Manishearth see this meta question.. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions

Comment: @georg best fit. Unfortunately, the "general reference" option is only enabled as a trial on some sites. Still, current consensus seems to be that such questions ought to be discouraged.

Comment: Hmm, that meta post is from the earlier days of SO, when rules were much more lax. Issue is, we want good, conceptual questions, not stuff that can be easily Googled. Such stuff is better asked on [chat]. in this case, it _did_ get a conceptual answer, though the question itself still remains not that good. And don't let closes discourage you--if you can improve it, it may be reopened. If you still feel that this shouldn't have been closed, feel free to post on [meta], we can see what the community thinks. (as it is I was unsure about closing this, but another mod agreed)

Comment: You may not realize, but Google has picked up this question and answer as the featured link at the top of the page for "colour of ozone".  The advice to google it leads back here. What's more, another chemistry stack exchange answer similarly closed also is in the first page. Also a Wikipedia article on Ozone which says almost nothing on the topic. 

Luckily Quora comes second. I've added an answer there for those wondering where they can find the colour of ozone https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-colour-of-ozone/answer/Robert-Walker-5. Others here might like to add answers there as well.

Answer (score 3):

Ozone gas does indeed have a slight blue color. It is dark blue in a liquid form and purple-black in solid form.

The color comes from the fact that it absorbs all wavelengths of light other than those in the blue region. As the phase changes, the molecules get closer together, shifting the area of absorption, changing the color of the material.